# How to dock the "Identify" panel to the top or bottom of the QGIS window?

Tags: qgis

I'd like to dock the "identify" window to the top or bottom of the QGIS window. Docking to the left and right seems to work fine (a blue area indicates the new position of the panel after releasing the mouse button). However, when dragging the panel to the top or bottom of the window, no blue area is shown.

However, docking other panels (e.g. "View Results") to the top or bottom works?
I'm using QGIS 3.2.3.

Comment: How do I dock the "Identify Results" in QGIS 3.12.2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure that the panel is attached to the *Processing Toolbox*, in the form of a tab.

[image: moved1]

- Move all the panel to top or bottom of the QGIS window.

[image: moved2]

- Take only the *Processing Toolbox* tab and drag it to its original place.

[image: moved3]

Answer (score 3):

Double-clicking the top grey title bar of the Identify window will get it to dock to the QGIS window.  I'm using QGIS 3.4.2.